# Syntax error or access violation 1064 using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following code to either insert new row, or update existing one, giving that `id` is unique in the table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(id, columnTwo, columnThree, columnFour)    
VALUES (:id, :columnTwo, :columnThree, :columnFour) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (columnTwo=:columnTwo, columnThree=:columnThree, columnFour=:columnFour)"; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':columnTwo', $columnTwo);
$stmt->bindParam(':columnThree', $columnThree);
$stmt->bindParam(':columnFour', $columnFour);

$stmt->execute();
```

If I remove the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part, it inserts the row with no problems (assuming the unique key `id` doesn't already exist), but as I add this part, I get the following error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '(columnTwo='some_value',
>   columnThree='some_value', columnFour='some_value')' at line 3"}

Comment: Try without the brackets after update

Comment: That worked! thank you

Comment: @deceze Are you sure this qualifies as a typo? In my opinion this was a misunderstanding of the syntax, and this is why I answered. A typo would be an accidental mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MYSQL Syntax states that the `assignment_list` is in the format:

```
assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

and the syntax for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is:

```
[ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]
```

There are no brackets allowed according to syntax. 
Compare it with the syntax for VALUES:

```
{VALUES | VALUE} (value_list) [, (value_list)] ...
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: it's not MySQL syntax it's some kind of BNF (Backus–Naur Form) syntax.. But it can be hard to read and understand when you don't know the syntax rules. The best examples on how to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` are [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @RaymondNijland The title of that page is literally "INSERT Syntax". BNF is the standard and most understandable notation of describing syntax IMHO. The page you linked gives examples how to use it, but doesn't define the syntax.

Comment: "BNF is the standard and most understandable notation of describing syntax IMHO" I know, iám pretty sure not every programmer knows how to read it and how to use BNF to "convert" it into a working SQL syntax query.   That's why i have included the SQL examples

Comment: Besides in some cases the BNF in the MySQL docs does not define all possiblities in the SQL syntax whats why i said i can be hard to read and understand and how to convert the BNF into valid SQL syntax.. the INSERT `VALUES()` for example is defined as..  `value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

value_list:
    value [, value]` and `{VALUES | VALUE} (value_list) [, (value_list)] ...` and didn't define `expr`so whats `expr` in the BNF syntax?  Now i know (My)SQL syntax so i know the BNF means anny valid (My)SQL expression here for example `... VALUES((SELECT 1))` is valid